# Using React Native + Redux + Axios + Redux-Promise behind corporate proxy

Tags: proxy, react-native, redux, react-redux, axios

I'm building a simple 'API Endpoint tester' in RN (Android) using Redux + Axios (mainly for testing internal API's). I've signed the app and deployed it to the physical phone which has access to the internal network. I'm able to hit several external API's (jsonplaceholder, github, wikipedia, etc) and get the proper response but when I try to hit any internal API I get the following response:

```
{
 "config": {
   "transformRequest": {},
   "transformResponse": {},
   "headers": {
     "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, /"
   },
   "timeout": 0,
   "xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN",
   ...
   ...
}
```

This is basically the default config object that is part of the payload.
When I run the exact code in a React (not RN) application it works as I expect. Am I missing something here? I've also tried using fetch() with no luck.